# How can I restore some of my data according to specific data in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

We use Azure mobile service to deploy user's datas and due to an error, some users lost their data and made them so angry.

Do we have a chance to restore some users's datas according to specific date in Azure Sql databases?

For example, User can be register before 25 April 2016 but their app version lower than 30. I want to define these users and to restore their data.

Comment: Where exactly do you store the user data?

Comment: I  store user data in Sql db that is used by my mobil service.

Comment: Do you mean Azure Sql DB?

Comment: Exactly yes it Azure sql db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use SQL DB Point in time restore feature to restore the database just before the time you dropped the records. How long you can go back is based on your database service tier / edition. PITR will create a new database at that point in time, and you have to copy the records manually to your production database

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-sql-database-point-in-time-restore/

Comment: I did it succesfully. Thank you

Comment: Great to hear! Thank you!